# VBA Excel - Faster Execute - Copy Sheet (with charts/objects) from closed file

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, file-io

I am hoping to find a way to help this code run faster; so this is the path im following to try and achieve this -

current time - 23 seconds, most of it opening & closing files.

So I am attempting to pull data from files without opening them.
I've seen Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 but I have not idea how to use it to get the entire sheet, warts and all.

I've seen a lot of solutions that pull data from cells and gets sheet names -
I want my entire sheet, all objects on that sheet, its headers, footers, everything.

This is the macro I'd like to apply it to:

```
Sub DirPDF_Long_Sections(LongFolderPath As String)


' ####################################################################################
' #  INTRO

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose
'     This procedure assists the user to put all long sections from a folder into one
'     PDF file. This makes it convieniet to share the long sections & print them.
'
'     THIS PROCEDURE USES DIR instead of FSO
'

' ####################################################################################
' #  DECLAIRATIONS

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' OBJECTS

Dim LongFolder       As String
Dim LongFile         As String
Dim OpenLong         As Workbook
Dim ExportWB         As Workbook
'Dim FileSystemObj    As New FileSystemObject

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' VARIABLES

Dim count            As Long
Dim DefaultPrinter   As String
Dim DefaultSheets    As Variant
Dim FirstSpace       As Long
Dim LastSpace        As Long
Dim start_time, end_time


' ####################################################################################
' # PROCEDURE CODE


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' optimise speed

start_time = Now()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Print the Files in the Folder:

DefaultSheets = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook                       '// save default setting
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1                                   '// create a one worksheet workbook
Set ExportWB = Workbooks.Add
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = DefaultSheets                       '// re-set application to default

LongFile = Dir(LongFolderPath & "\*PipeLongSec*", vbNormal)

While LongFile <> vbNullString                                        '// loop through all the files in the folder

    FirstSpace = InStr(1, LongFile, " ")                      '// record position of first space character
    LastSpace = InStr(FirstSpace + 1, LongFile, " ")          '// record position of last space character

    Set OpenLong = Workbooks.Open(LongFile)                   '// open the file

    OpenLong.Sheets("Long Sections").Copy After:=ExportWB.Sheets(ExportWB.Sheets.count)
                                                                      '// copy sheet into export workbook

    ExportWB.Sheets(ExportWB.Sheets.count).Name = Mid(LongFile, FirstSpace + 1, LastSpace - FirstSpace - 1)
                                                                      '// rename sheet we just moved to its pipe number

    OpenLong.Close                                            '// close the file

    LongFile = Dir()                                          '// get next file

Wend


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Delete the other worksheet in the temporary workbook


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ExportWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Send Workbook to PDF - in save location

ExportWB.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, LongFolderPath & "\" & "LongSectionCollection " & Replace(Date, "/", "-")
ExportWB.Close SaveChanges:=False


'#####################################################################################
'#  END PROCEDURE

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set OpenLong = Nothing

end_time = Now()
MsgBox (DateDiff("s", start_time, end_time))



End Sub
```

Comment: The faster method would be to create a copy of the workbook (via code) and delete the unwanted sheets so that you are left with the sheet(s) that you require

Answer (score 1):

Add Option Explicit before any code at the top

Convert DefaultSheets to CLngPtr(DefaultSheets)

Convert Long data types to CLngPtr(variable)

Convert to CDate(Start_Time)

Convert to CDate(End_Time)

Comment: Hello there! it has been a very long time since i worked this project, no matter I still appreciate your answer. Any chance you could explain that a little further for me please?

Comment: Yes, using defined variable types for all your variables and avoiding variant variables will speed up the code.  For large files, it is better to use long integer pointers LngPtr instead of integer data types. DefaultSheets should be converted to Integer or Long Integer Pointer as it is a count I assume.  Converting the start time and end time to CDate, should convert then to Date/Time.

Comment: totally agree on option explicit, it is in the code, just not this segment of the larger project - Is it good practice that I have it at the beginning of every sub routine?

Comment: ps. sorry about the huge delays, my work does not require me to delve into this anymore - although i still want to know. I'm knowledge hungry.

Answer (score 0):

No worries. They should be defined in the dim statement if they would remain the same data type. If this data type changes throughout the code then use as variant in the dim statement and use the conversion functions found in the object browser to convert the data types as needed.

Comment: @user3432631, Mind = blown! my brother, I get it. and for mhatch I think if you scan through my code you will find that I use a lot of variables that have variable data types, essentially because yours truely was too silly to define the actual data type. A long time ago I was working on this, I cant go back and try it anymore (Damn!!). What I have learned and hopefully anyone reading this will learn, VB runs faster when you explicitly define your data types. We could use a page somewhere with a few tips and tricks for VB for applications - im sure it exits somewhere!!!!!!

Comment: @mhatch - see above comment - let us know if this is helping at all for what you are working on